# De quelle façon décririez-vous l’emplacement des deux maisons (1 et 2) à qui voudrait se repérer sans numéro civique ?

Tags: choix-de-mot, formulation-idiomatique, constructions, formulation, reformulation

De quelle façon décririez-vous l’emplacement des deux maisons (1 et 2) à qui voudrait se repérer sans numéro civique. [image]

Auparavant il s’agissait de deux rues distinctes avec deux noms différents, le segment débouchant sur la 132 avait pour nom la rue *des Sapins* et les trois autres segments qui, avec le quatrième, forment un carré qui se rapproche d’un rectangle (disons un carré en manière de simplification et pour rester cohérent avec le type de rue), se nommait la rue *des Pins*. Dorénavant il n’y a qu’une unique rue appelée *Carré Pear-Arbor* . Pour la 2, je décrirais l’emplacement ainsi: la maison est située au premier coin de rue, là où se trouve le point d’intersection. Pour la 1, j’aurais tendance à dire que c’est la maison située en face du premier tournant, là où la rue s’entrecoupe elle-même (il s’agit de la même rue).

Là où je me questionne, c’est qu’étant donné la figure géométrique que forme la rue, à savoir un carré qui frise le rectangle, les deux petits segments de droite (le dessin n’est pas à l’échelle, il est question des deux segments parallèles à la 132) forment-ils deux ou quatre tournants? Et peut-on parler d’un point d’intersection pour une même rue?

Je souhaiterais qu’on me donne la description que vous feriez de l’emplacement de chacune des maisons situées sur l’image insérée en fichier joint du point de vue d’un automobiliste qui roulerait sur la 132 en direction de *Carré Pear-Arbor.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Voilà une description qui allie l'image aux notions strictes de repérage. Je  n'ai pas cherché à la  rendre le plus court possible, ce qui pourrait peut-être se faire avantageusement.  Il y a une certaine répétition que je ne sais évaluer  ni comme  étant utile ni comme étant excessive. Je laisse le soin à qui voudra s'en occuper d'extraire de cette description assez complète ce qui pourrait être considéré comme le strict minimum utile.

Il me semble que l'on doive pouvoir parler de l'intersection d'une  rue avec elle-même (mais je ne me sers pas de cette idée). Il y a, dans la rue elle-même, cinq tournants (mais je ne me sers pas du concept de tournant).

*Description*

La rue « Carré Pear Arbor » est une rue dont le nom ne décrit qu'une partie de sa forme puisque ce n'est pas celle d'un carré mais celle d'un carré dont l'un des côtés est prolongé d'un tronçon rectiligne de longueur à peu près égale à lui-même. C'est une rue qui rappelle un drapeau au mât très court, le mât et le pourtour du drapeau constituant la rue. C'est en fait plutôt une impasse qu'une rue : on y entre par la rue 132 et on en sort par la même rue, au même point, ou, en d'autres termes, au pied du drapeau. Par rapport à la direction est-ouest de la rue 132 elle ouvre à la perpendiculaire vers le nord, « le drapeau flottant à gauche ». Après avoir pénétré dans la rue Carré Pear Arbor on trouve la maison 1 à droite juste avant le segment de retour de la rue sur elle-même, et on trouve la maison 2 à la fin de ce segment, à gauche. Les deux maisons sont donc orientées à la perpendiculaire l'une de l'autre, la seconde  dans le coin du carré et la première à proximité, de l'autre côté de la rue, mais du côté droit du premier segment, celui qui correspond au mât. De la façade de l'une on peut donc apercevoir celle de  l'autre.

Answer (score 2):

Je dirais que la maison 1 se situe à droite, à la hauteur de la première intersection, et que la maison 2 se situe dans la première rue à gauche, sur la droite.